Non custodial bitcoin wallet creation using passkey
Ethereum allows creation of smart wallet with passkeys using ERC-4437. Can a similar thing be implemented in bitcoin without any changes in the bitcoin network protocol?

A web app / browser extension bitcoin wallet app
Authentication / signing is done via passkey in non custodial fashion

Please provide full details on how this can be implemented. Where/how will the BIP32 seed phrase be stored and what are the security implications?
